# Python: connecting to the IP of a device connected on a wifi repeater (WiFi NAT Router)

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests, wifi, router

I have a working python script that retrieve data from a wifi device (a NodeMCU*) by connecting to its IP address:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://192.168.1.12/data.json')
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

This script works because my computer and my device are both connected to the same wifi SSID (let's called it the main SSID).

But my wifi signal is not strong enough for my device (because it is outdoor), so I have set up a wifi repeater** that connects to the main SSID and create an Access Point. I have then connected my device to this wifi repeater Access Point.

I used the new IP address of my device (`10.24.1.2`*** ) in the script above but this only works when I disconnect my computer from the main SSID and connect it to the wifi repeater Access Point. But I do not want to do that : my computer should remain on the main SSID and my device should be on the wifi repeater Access Point.

So my question is: How can I retrieve the data.json from this device which is connected to the wifi repeater, while my computer remains on the main SSID?

I looked into port-forward which the wifi repeater could do but my device doesn't seem to have a port: if I connect to `http://10.24.1.2/data.json` I see a bunch of data but if I connect to `http://10.24.1.2/data.json:3` (or any number) I get "Not found".

But I can set up an API on my device with a specific server, path and port (though need to do some research to know how to use it)

[image]

---

*) The device is a [lufdaten sensor](https://github.com/opendata-stuttgart/sensors-software), built from a nodemcu
**) My wifi repeater is another nodemcu programmed with this https://github.com/martin-ger/esp_wifi_repeater

***) I retrieve the new IP of my device via a TCP/telnet connection to my wifi repeater IP address with [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "repeater" does not extend the existing network as most WiFi repeaters do  but is instead a WiFi router which creates a new network with a different address space. Your main WiFi router ("main SSID") is then just a single device inside this new network, which means it will use NAT to provide access from any devices inside "main SSID" to the "repeater SSID".

But since this kind of NAT dynamically maps multiple IP to a single IP it can work by design only in one direction: connection from inside the "main network" (192.168.1/24) to the "repeater network" (10.24.1/24) can be created but no connection from the repeater network to the main network. That's actually the same reason why devices inside a home network are not directly reachable from the internet.

To make this work you would need to create an explicit port forwarding if your router for "main SSID" can do this. Alternatively you could use a repeater which does not create a new network but which just extends the existing network. No idea if your existing device can do this since it is explicitly documented as "a WiFi **NAT** router".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can set my wifi repeater to `automesh`. Then "configuring the "Soft AP Settings" is not required as in automesh mode these settings are identical to the "STA Settings". The same ssid will be offered by all connected ESP repeaters." But still with this configuration, I can't access my device URL.

Comment: Concerning the port forwarding, my main SSID can forward port. I have set this `WifiRepeater TCP Port 7777 192.168.1.39 999` [7777 is the port I use in Putty to send commands to my wifi repeater, 192.168.1.39 is my wifi repeater on my main SSID and 999 is just a random number]. I tried to connect to the device IP (`http://10.24.1.2:999/`) but it doesn't work. Are these the settings I should use?

Comment: @MagTun: if you access your sensor from within the main SSID with `http://192.168.1.12/data.json` you need to have a port forwarding on the AP for the main SSID from 999 to `192.168.1.12` port 80 in order to access your sensor with `http://10.24.1.2:999/data.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete Steffen Ullrich's answer:

Steps to retrieve the json available on the wifi repeater network on `http://10.24.1.2/data.json` from your computer connected on the main SSID/network:

1) In the wifi repeater create a port forwarding (the wifi repeater I use can be controlled via TCP/telnet so this command is sent via putty if my computer is connected to the main SSID or via arduino serial monitor if my computer is connected to the wifi repeater)

```
portmap add TCP 999 10.24.1.2 80
```

999 :  a number chosen randomly 
10.24.1.2 : IP address of the device connected to the wifi repeater network (retrieved via command "show dhcp")
80 : default port for HTTP request

2) While connected to main SSID, go to `http://192.168.1.39:999/data.json` (change 999 according to the number you choose in step 1)

---

If you wan to access your device from any internet connection (from anywhere), you need to create a port forward also on the main SSID/network (I had to go to 192.168.1.1 then v4 network > NAT):

```
WifiRepeater   TCP  Port    8432 192.168.1.39   999
```

- wifiRepeater : custom name of port forwarding
- TCP: it's the protocol used
- Port: it's the type used
- 8432: a random number cf the explanation from [howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/):

> You can use any number you want here between 1 and 65353, but
>   practically most of the lower numbers are taken up by standard
>   services (like email and web servers) and many of the higher numbers
>   are assigned to fairly common applications. With that in mind, we’d
>   recommend picking a number above 5,000 and, to be extra safe, using
>   Ctrl+F to search this [long list of TCP/UDP port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) to make sure
>   you’re not selecting a port that conflicts with an existing service
>   you’re already  using.

- 192.168.1.39  : IP address of wifi repeater on livebox
- 999 : the number chosen randomly in step 1